# Google Compute Engine on Docker, how to auto restart app on crash?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, dockerfile, app.yaml

I'm running a NodeJS app on Google Compute Engine using Custom Runtimes with Google App Engine. That uses a Dockerfile and app.yaml, and all I do is just `gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml --set-default`.

When my app crashes, I have to manually stop and start the app module using `gcloud preview app modules stop default --version 12345678` and `gcloud preview app modules start default --version 12345678` manually from my own computer.

Note this is different from restarting VM instance. It's about restarting the `app module`. Docs here https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/preview/app/modules/start

Is there a way to automate the process, maybe by specifying some `restartOnFailure` spec in the `app.yaml` or `Docker` file, so Docker will restart an app on crash?

Comment: very helpful post, wondered about the same thing. Did you get anything till now or not ?? please reply must.